# Doesn't send email by yii

Tags: php, email, yii

I have a yii program. Version of yii is 1.1.17.my php version is 7.1.8. I want to send an email in my program, test many extension of yii but I haven't any result.

last of my test, I use smtp extension:
in main.php (config folder):

```
    'components' => array(
    'Smtpmail'=>array(
                'class'=>'application.extensions.smtpmail.PHPMailer',
                'Host'=>"smtp.gmail.com",
                'Username'=>'MyGmailId@gmail.com',
                'Password'=>'myPassword',
                'Mailer'=>'smtp',
                'Port'=>'465',
                'SMTPAuth'=>true,
            ),
)
```

and in controller:

```
$mail=Yii::app()->Smtpmail;
            $mail->CharSet="UTF-8";
            $mail->SetFrom('MyGmailId@gmail.com',''));
            $mail->Subject    = $subject;
            $mail->MsgHTML($text);
            $mail->AddAddress($email, "");
            if(!$mail->Send()) {
                return $mail->ErrorInfo;
            }else {
                return true;
            }
```

I do setting in `php.ini` and send `sendmail.ini` about `openssl` too.

I have this error:

> The following From address failed: MyGmailId@gmail.com : Called Mail()
>   without being connected.

Comment: Are you sure that credentials for Username and Password is correct?

Comment: @Justinas yes, I'm sure.

Comment: try by adding this 'SMTPSecure' => 'ssl',

Comment: If you have enabled 2-Step-Verification for your Google account then you need to generate app password 
as described in "How to generate an App password" on https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/185833

'SMTPSecure' => 'ssl' is necessary (as commented by Ahmed Sunny)

To get more information about problem from PHPMailer you can set: SMTPDebug = 3.

And good guide for investigating the problem is https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Troubleshooting